# Change X-Frame_options from Deny always to Sameorigin in NGINX

Tags: nginx, odoo, odoo-10, x-frame-options

I set `add_header X-Frame-Options deny always;`. 
Now i want to change it to `SAMEORIGIN`. To do that i changed the in  `/etc/niginx/sites-available/my_domain`

```
#add_header X-Frame-Options deny always;
add_header X-Frame-Options sameorigin always;
```

But header part it still showing X-Frame-Options DENY

Here is the Screen shot:

[image]

How can i change this?

Comment: Did you restart nginx after making the change?

Comment: @Calum Halpin: Yes

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
```

and restart Nginx. I tested "add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN always;" and Nginx error log reports:

```
invalid number of arguments in "add_header" directive in ...
```